# Pandas giving KeyError:0 after creating a new environment with python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, virtualenv

```
df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0][0][1:]
```

is giving me the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shijith/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete.py", line 76, in <module>
    stock_Symbols = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0][0]
  File "/Users/shijith/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2927, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/shijith/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2659, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

`df = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')[0]` is working properly, error occurs when trying to slice again.

I am using anaconda and have python 3.7 installed on my base environment. But since i had to use H20, i created a new environment with python 3.6.

In the base version the above code was working without an error.
Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be because, I used `source activate py36env` to activate the created environment and installed packages to it( i am using conda 4.6.14).

> As per conda docs to activate a created environment use:
>
> *For conda 4.6 and later versions*, use.
>      `conda activate` and `conda deactivate`
>
> *For conda versions prior to 4.6*, use:
>     Windows: `activate` and `deactivate`
>     Linux and macOS: `source activate` and `source deactivate`

I had to delete that environment and create again (`conda create -n envname python=3.5 pandas scikit-learn`), 
activated using `conda activate envname`

now its working